# Flow is giving SyntaxError on imports

Tags: flowtype

Here's my code:

```
// @flow
import { EntityModel } from '@http-utils/hateoas';
```

I compile it:

```
babel src/ -d dist/
```

Then I run it, but I get a runtime error:

```
$ node dist/http-utils-hateoas-example.js
import { EntityModel } from '@http-utils/hateoas';
       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

Based on Flow documentation, my babel config has only `@babel/preset-flow`. Looks like this is only stripping flow. How do I configure babel to do additional compilation down to code that can be run on nodejs?

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-flow"
  ]
}
```

Comment: From stack trace looks like you're trying to load ESModule using Common JS

Comment: Hi Aleksey, I have added my babel config to the question. Trying to figure out how to make babel generate Common JS, so that it can be executed by node.js

Comment: Problem solved! All I needed was another preset: @babel/preset-env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple. All I needed was another preset to transpile down to CommonJS.

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-flow",
    @babel/preset-env
  ]
}
```